# Where can I set the second language for JHipster when I run "yo jhipster" and say yes to internationalization?

Tags: jhipster

By default we get English and French. I would like to get Spanish. Can someone tell me where to change the second language from French to Spanish?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to install Spanish and then you can remove French.
You can find the instructions here: [Installing new languages](http://jhipster.github.io/installing_new_languages.html)

Though there are instructions to remove an existing language (at the end of the page) I have found more practical to just leave the files for the default languages (English and French) because they are going to reappear when you update jHipster version. If you don't want them in the menu, just delete the value in the file *src/main/webapp/components/language/language.service.js*:

```
.constant('LANGUAGES', [
  'en', /* 'fr', */
  //JHipster will add new languages here
'es'
]
```